# Uniform convergent to a discontinous function

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Can a sequence of functions converge uniformly to a discontinuous function on a set?

Comment: It can. Consider a sequence of functions $f_n(x)=sgn(x)$. It converges uniformly to $sgn(x)$ on $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if the functions themselves are discontinuous.